# Deontic “must”, “have to” and “had to”

Tags: etymology, deontic-vs-epistemic, have-to-versus-must

In English, to express strong obligation we can use either *must* or *have (got) to*. Grammars remind us that ***must*** is often used to express internal (personal) obligation, deduction (likelihood), and exhortation.

1. *The insulin shots for your pet must be given at twelve-hour intervals*. (deontic)
2. *We must be late, there's no one in the foyer*. ([epistemic](https://allthingslinguistic.com/post/138048860136/the-difference-between-epistemic-deontic#notes))
3. *If he wants to be healthier he must exercise*. (deontic)

However, they tell us that ***have to*** tends to convey the rules and laws of an external authority which we have no choice but to follow and/or obey. The longer construction ***have got to*** is normally classified as being informal, and idiomatic in speech.

4. *I'm sorry but we have to leave early.* ([deontic](https://allthingslinguistic.com/post/138048860136/the-difference-between-epistemic-deontic#notes))
5. (a) *You've got to believe me*. (informal)
   (b) *You gotta believe me*. (very informal)

In my experience,  this distinction between internal and external authority is very hazy and subjective, with the exception of sentence 2 where no obligation is expressed, native speakers use *must* and *have (got) to* more or less interchangeably.

In order to prove my point, consider how English expresses obligation in the past, the form ***had to*** is used whereas *must* is used with the perfect infinitive, i.e. must + have + past participle, to make speculations about the past and to convey certainty.

1. *The insulin shots **had to** be given at twelve-hour intervals*.
2. *We **must have been** late, there was no one in the foyer*
3. *If he wanted to be healthier he **had to** exercise*
4. *We apologised and said we **had to** leave early.*
5. *You **had to** believe me*.

In the sentences with *had to*, the distinction between internal and external obligation is completely lost, greater context is required to know who the person or entity of authority is.  In other words, HAD TO functions as the past for both HAVE TO and MUST. If this distinction, which many grammar sites (see below) explain is relevant, why does it disappear in the past?

### Questions

1. How and when did *have to*  express the sense of obligation? What void did it fill?
2. If deductions (epistemic) in the past can be expressed with must + have + PP what happened to deontic *must* in the past? Is there an etymological explanation?
3. What happened to the distinction between internal (subjective) and external (objective) obligation when we speak about the past? Did it ever exist?

Sources:
[Modals (1) Obligation](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/modals-1)
[What's the difference between must and have to?](http://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-must-have-to.php)
[must / have to / have got to](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/youmeus/learnit/learnitv127.shtml)
[Modals to express obligation: MUST, HAVE (GOT) TO](http://www.grammaring.com/modals-to-express-obligation-must-have-got-to)
[English modal verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verbs#Must_and_have_to)
[Categorization principles of modal meaning categories](https://journals.openedition.org/anglophonia/476#tocto2n3)

Comment: ***To have to***  for "must" (1570s) is from sense of "possess as a duty or thing to be done" (Old English). https://www.etymonline.com/word/have - ***Must*** - Used as present tense from c. 1300, from the custom of using past subjunctive as a moderate or polite form of the present. https://www.etymonline.com/word/must

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/206053/must-obligation-x-certainty-which-meaning-developed-first-in-the-english-lan

Comment: The relevant OED entry for *have to*: a. To be under an obligation to do something; to be required to; to need to. This usage developed from sense 8a: the duty or thing to be done was initially expressed as a direct object of the verb (*to have something to do*, sense 8a), then in an infinitive clause (*to have to do something*, this sense). Because word order was unfixed in early periods, it is difficult to determine precisely when this sense arose; the first unambiguous examples are those in which the verb in the infinitive clause is intransitive. (continued in the next comment)

Comment: (continuing from the previous comment)
Attestations such as quots. OE   and a1225   are syntactically ambiguous, and may be transitional from sense 8a. It has also been suggested that in early use the construction may occasionally approach a periphrastic or modal future in sense rather than more narrowly implying obligation (compare the Latin constructions rendered in the quots.):
(continued in the next comment)

Comment: (continuing from the previous comment)
OE   West Saxon Gospels: Matt. (Corpus Cambr.) xx. 22   *Mage gyt drincan þone calic ðe ic to drincenne hæbbe* [L. bibiturus sum].
a1225  (▸c1200)    Vices & Virtues (1888) 27   *All ðat ȝe habbeð to donne [L. uultis facere], an godes name doþ hit, mit gode ȝeleaue.*

Comment: I think there is some stuff I disagree with. I don't think "had to" is the "past of must" with an if clause.   "If he wants to be healthier, he must exercise". The past of that is: If he had wanted to be healthier, he would have had to have exercised. For me, "If he wanted" is an unreal situation, not a past tense: If he wanted to be healthier, he would have to exercise. But he doesn't, so he isn't.  VERSUS I want to be healthier, so I must exercise. I wanted to be healthier, so I had to exercise. There yes, it is the past of must. But the if clause one is not one I personally would write.

Comment: "***they*** tell us"? There are many many zombie rules about modal usage; I don't think there's either salvation or unanimity among experts about the general rules. A great deal of what one finds in popular grammar sites is personal preference or habit projected as The Norm without evidence.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, the "rule" about 'have to' and 'must' is a poor one.

Comment: @linguistictum You had the basis of a complete answer there. Why restrict yourself to comment ? ?

Comment: The question was specifically about the past tense of must expressed as had to, not its origins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> (1) How and when did *have to* express the sense of obligation? What void did it fill?

*Have to* is an example of what's called a ***[Periphrastic Modal](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html)*** (*periphrastic* is a technical term for 'paraphrased', meaning taking more than one word). Most English modal auxiliary verbs have at least one matching periphrastic modal construction, viz:

- *must ~ have to*
- *should ~ ought to*
- *can ~ (be) able to*
- *may ~ (be) possible*
- *will ~ (be) going to*
- *will ~ (be) willing to*

These constructions are common and have been around a long time. They arose because, as mentioned in another answer, English modal auxiliaries are defective verbs and therefore can't be used in many places where they could make sense because their morphology forbids it.

Thus, while it's possible to speak of a past obligation, you can't use *must* in the past to do so

- **He musted go to the dentist yesterday.*

but rather a periphrastic modal that does have a past tense

- *He had to go to the dentist yesterday.*

Similarly for infinitives and participles

- **I would hate to must rewrite my paper.*
- *I would hate to have to rewrite my paper.*
- **He's musting rewrite his paper*
- *He's having to rewrite his paper*
- **He has musted rewrite his paper*
- *He has had to rewrite his paper*

And similarly for the other periphrastic modals (examples left as an exercise).

> (2) If deductions (epistemic) in the past can be expressed with *must* + *have* + `PP` what happened to deontic *must* in the past? Is there an etymological explanation?

Oh, yes. It turns out that *must* is itself based on an old preterite form, and there simply **is** no present form, which would likely be something like **muss* if it existed in English.

German still has inflected modals, and the 3s present tense form of the modal verb *müssen* is *er muss* 'he must', while the past tense form is *er musste* 'he had to'. The final *-t* in German is the past tense suffix, and the final *-t* in English *must* **used to** be a past tense morpheme, but now it's just part of the word.

> (3) What happened to the distinction between internal (subjective) and external (objective) obligation when we speak about the past? Did it ever exist?

Nothing happened to it. It's a zombie rule. Some people believe that it is real and that they always mean things that way, whatever they may actually say. But in fact it is not anything like general, as you note, and it doesn't seem to describe many uses of *must* and *have to*, let alone other modal-paraphrase pairs.

**Executive Summary**: Don't believe everything you read. Especially not about English grammar.

Comment: There was a present form in OE: mot. Any idea where this internal/external nonsense came from? My first thought was, “He has to go to the bathroom,” which is about as internal as you can get.

Comment: Wishful thinking by English teachers who never tried to find counterexamples. There's a lot of that around. As for _mot_, I forgot _so mote it be_; sorry.

Comment: @KarlG I don't lke the rule, but I could see how someone could defend it by saying that in *I have to go to the bathroom*, the *have to* refers to an obligation that does not exist in my will, but outside of my will; it is the call of nature, not necessarily of me. I don't want to go to the bathroom at the 1:00 mark of the game but  have to.

Comment: @user: In this age of language corpora, I expect broad claims like this "rule" to be supported by statistics.

Answer (score 4):

"Must" is what's known as a "defective" verb, or one that list lacking particular conjugations. "Must" is the only form of the verb; it doesn't change for third versus first person, and it has no past tense form. And in fact, "must" doesn't really make sense in the past tense. Note that in the deductive sense, "must" is still in the present tense, even though it is speaking of past events. In "We must have been late, there was no one in the foyer", us having been late occurred in the past, but this having to be true is occurring in the present: it is *presently* true that us having been late occurred.

Comment: No verb in English except "be" changes from the first to second person. I also don't think English  has conjugations, only verb forms. -s, -es, -ing, -ed.

Comment: @LAmbie Almost every verb changes from first to second person. You presented examples in your very comment: "changes" is the second person version of "change". And the idea that English doesn't have conjugations is quite the novel one.

Comment: I love tea; you love tea, s/he loves tea. ***Third person, not second person.*** English has verb forms.  Have a look: http://www.as.wvu.edu/~pconner/Q&G3.html  English is said to have conjugations because the grammarians were originally Latinists. Today, there is no need for it.

Comment: **All** modal auxiliaries are defective verbs in English; they have no infinitive form, no present participle form, no past participle form, and no finite inflected forms. One form does all, no changes allowed.

Comment: @Lambie: English verbs are said to be conjugated because one doesn't wish to sever present day language from centuries of its history. If you read Shakespeare, you need to conjugate.

Comment: @JohnLawler So, you're analyzing "shall" and "should" as being completely different verbs, not different forms of the same verb? And similarly may/might, can/could, will/would?

Comment: @Acccumulation47: Yes. They used to be inflectional variants like _see_ and _saw_, but now they're just different auxiliaries, with their own uses and histories. _Shall_, for instance, is used in spoken English only in the question constructions _Shall I ...?_, which is an offer by the speaker, and _Shall we ...?_, which is an invitation by the speaker (_Shall I close the blinds? Shall we dance?_) _Should_, on the other hand, has a different meaning, and has nothing to do with the past. As to Shakespeare, he didn't write in Modern English.