# How do I explain the grammatical construction of 'The dog had to be taken to the vet'

Tags: grammar

The following test question appeared for turning regular sentences into questions without using 'wh- words':

*The dog had to be taken to the vet because he had eaten a whole shoe.*

The answer should be: *Did the dog have to be taken to the vet because he had eaten a whole shoe?*

However, many students mistook 'had' for an auxiliary verb, and turned the sentence into: *Had the dog to be taken to the vet.* (Switching the auxiliary verb and the subject.)

I have been trying to think of a way to explain this to them when we come to discussing it, but I'm having trouble picking apart the grammatical construction of 'had to be taken'.

It looks like the present perfect, but then why wouldn't the auxiliary rule work, and I am not sure how to place the 'to be'.

I feel like I should know what this is, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/446403/deontic-must-have-to-and-had-to ; look especially at Mari-Lou A's sources and the top answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auxiliary **have** partners with the past participle of the verb, not with the infinitive.

**To be taken** is the passive infinitive.

**To take** is the normal (active) infinitive.

> My car had *to be taken* to the shop.
>
> I had *to take* my car to the shop.

The subject changes but the verb **have** has the same meaning in the active and passive. It expresses the idea of a need or necessity, like **must**.

> You have to get some sleep. You look really tired.
>
> You have to drink water to stay alive.

The nature of the necessity is expressed in the infinitive clause, **to get some sleep** and **to drink water (to stay alive)**.

Comment: auxiliary have partners?

Comment: @Lambie: What is it you don't understand about the verb *partners*?

Comment: /Auxiliary have partner/ must be some kind of typo. Why not fix it?

Comment: /Auxiliary have partner/ is a reado not a typo

Comment: You've lost me, not that I was following to begin with.

Comment: I have no idea what it means. It is not English as far as I'm concerned. Auxiliary verbs or auxiliaries, but not a singular like that with "have partners".

Comment: @Lambie: Are you reading this on a device that does not display words in bold by any chance?

Comment: You are trying to say: The auxiliary "have" partners with the past participle of the verb. Yes, I cannot see bold, but still it would be confusing.

Comment: @Lambie lol, you need to fix the settings or system preferences of the smartphone/laptop/computer you're using. Now, I understand why you keep saying you cannot use bolding in your posts. Try here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307120/i-cannot-get-bold-or-italics-to-work